# How to draw the smooth lineplot and display the dates on the x-axis with python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I would really really appreciate it if you guys can point me to where to look. I have been trying to do it for 3 days and still can't find the right one. I need to draw the chart which looks as the first picture's chart and I need to display the dates on the X axis as it gets displayed on the second chart. I am complete beginner with seaborn, python and everything. I used lineplot first, which only met one criteria, display the dates on X-axis. But,  the lines are actually sharp like in the second picture rather than smooth like in the first picture. Then, I kept digging and found implot. With that, I could get the design of the chart I wanted (Smoothed chart). But, the problem is when I tried to display the dates on the X-axis, it didn't work. I got an error `could not convert string to float: '2022-07-27T13:31:00Z'`.

**Here is the code for implot, got the wanted plot design but date can't be displayed on X-axis**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

T = np.array([ "2022-07-27T13:31:00Z",
      "2022-08-28T13:31:00Z",
      "2022-09-29T13:31:00Z",
      "2022-10-30T13:31:00Z",])
power = np.array([10,25,60,42])

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'T': T, 'power': power})
    
sns.lmplot(x='T', y='power', data=df, ci=None, order=4, truncate=False)
```

If I use the number instead of date, the output is this. Exactly as I need

[image]

**Here is the code with which all the data gets displayed correctly. But, the plot design is not smoothed.**

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import scipy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.apply import frame_apply

years = ["2022-03-22T13:30:00Z",
      "2022-03-23T13:31:00Z",
      "2022-04-24T19:27:00Z",
      "2022-05-25T13:31:00Z",
      "2022-06-26T13:31:00Z",
      "2022-07-27T13:31:00Z",
      "2022-08-28T13:31:00Z",
      "2022-09-29T13:31:00Z",
      "2022-10-30T13:31:00Z",
      ]



feature_1 =[0,
      6,
      1,
      5,
      9,
      15,
      21,
      4,
      1,
     ]

data_preproc = pd.DataFrame({
    'Period': years, 
#     'Feature 1': feature_1,
#     'Feature 2': feature_2,
#     'Feature 3': feature_3,
#     'Feature 4': feature_4,
    "Feature 1" :feature_1
   })

data_preproc['Period'] = pd.to_datetime(data_preproc['Period'], 
                        format="%Y-%m-%d",errors='coerce')

data_preproc['Period'] = data_preproc['Period'].dt.strftime('%b')

# aiAlertPlot =sns.lineplot(x='Period', y='value', hue='variable',ci=None, 
#              data=pd.melt(data_preproc, ['Period']))

sns.lineplot(x="Period",y="Feature 1",data=data_preproc)


# plt.xticks(np.linspace(start=0, stop=21, num=52))
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.legend(title="features")
plt.ylabel("Alerts")
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

The output is this. Correct data, wrong chart design.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[lmplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lmplot.html) is a model based method, which requires numeric `x`. If you think the date values are evenly spaced, you can just create another variable `range` which is numeric and calculate `lmplot` on that variable and then change the `xticks` labels.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

T = np.array([ "2022-07-27T13:31:00Z",
      "2022-08-28T13:31:00Z",
      "2022-09-29T13:31:00Z",
      "2022-10-30T13:31:00Z",])
power = np.array([10,25,60,42])

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'T': T, 'power': power})
df['range'] = np.arange(df.shape[0])

sns.lmplot(x='range', y='power', data=df, ci=None, order=4, truncate=False)

plt.xticks(df['range'], df['T'], rotation = 45);
```

[image]